# SPICE Error in LM5117 Model in Microcap-12

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, simulation, spice, texas-instruments, pspice

I am trying to simulate SNVA829 (constant current constant voltage) schematic given in the application report from TI. I downloaded the spice model from TI site and imported it to microcap. When I tried to run the transient analysis I get the following error (seems it's a warning but it doesn't start or complete the simulation due to the warning); Warning: Extra Text 'TC=0,0' found. Part: X4.C_C1 File:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any idea on how to fix it? Is the model not correct?

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead

Comment: I don't think microcap likes TC in capacitor definitions.  Have you tried just removing the 'TC=0,0'?

Comment: I haven't tried to removing TC. Do I need to remove just "TC=0,0" or the whole line. I am not familiar with spice modeling, so didn't want to mess up the model

Comment: just the "TC=0,0" leave the rest

Comment: As you are finding, microcap is not as PSpice compatible as advertised...

Comment: Thanks; removing "TC=0,0" did work. Is TC the same as TC1,TC2? Just weird it works for resistors but not for capacitors. So, Microcap ignores capacitor changes due to temperature?

Comment: It is similar.  Yeah, my understanding is microcap doesn't use a tempco for caps at all.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: so now I am getting a singularity matrix error. Does that mean the circuit is wrong or I am missing a connection or the model is wrong?

Comment: That error means the solver couldn't converge on a solution for the circuit.  There are a LOT of reasons this can happen.  A bad or missing connection, a floating node, a broken/incompatible model, etc.  Make a new question and upload your file and maybe somebody can help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [manual page 556](https://www.iee.et.tu-dresden.de/%7Ejmueller/simulation/soft/microcap/MC12.RefManual.pdf), Microcap does not use temperature coefficients for capacitors like it does for resistors.

Removing "TC=0,0" will fix the problem